# Forward file attachment from Web API to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, httpwebrequest

I've got a Web API that returns a csv file. If I make a GET request e.g. via. a browser, I get a popup to ask where to download the csv file:

```
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

result.Content = new StringContent(res);
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = "export_" + DateTime.Now + ".csv"
};
return ResponseMessage(result);
```

I'm trying to call this API endpoint within another MVC controller and return the same csv file. How can I do this?

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAPIEndpoint);
httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

return httpResponse;
```

Comment: You should look at returning a FileStreamResult from your MVC action. Read the data from your API into a stream (e.g. memory stream) and then initialise and return a FileStreamResult with the content type set to "text/csv"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responses (routes) in MVC controllers are typically `ActionResult`s. The `httpResponse` object you are returning, is an `HttpWebResponse`.

You should probably read the csv content (using `GetResponseStream`) from the `httpResponse`, and then return that csv content using an appropriate MVC ActionResult.